# C# want to get network adapter status properties like Duration

Tags: c#, .net, networking

In C# how we can get value of Duration property available in status window of adapter.

[image]

Have tried several way available, like using NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() and also have tried WMI approach using class like [MSFT_NetAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh968170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but not getting correct value for Duration.

Can any one share how value of property is obtained. It Will be really helpful.

Comment: Not getting a correct value? What value are you getting?

Comment: @AustinTFrench I have used AddressValidLifetime property to get value, but value I get didn't match with status window of adapter.

Comment: AddressValidLifetime sounds like a DHCP setting - not the same as duration, try TimeOfLastReset instead.

Comment: If I were to guess, that sounds like the DHCP lease info.

Comment: @AlexK. Have tried TimeOfLastReset but it won't give us adapter Duration property. Value I received is timestamp of previous day which actually should be value of today as I believe Duration property value represent internet connection session time.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I have tried DHCP lease but it shows server lease time, and not a local machine lease time.

Comment: No, I meant on the field you mentioned previously. TimeOfLastReset looks right to me, but my machine currently appears blank on that field.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I found in this link https://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_networkadapter/#timeoflastreset_properties that says like property TimeOfLastReset is property which indicates when the network adapter was last reset. Duration is something different as I think it shows time ('hh:mm:ss') machine is connected with internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Add reference from Network List Manager 1.0 Type Library

```
            var manager = new NetworkListManager();
            var connectedNetworks = manager.GetNetworks(NLM_ENUM_NETWORK.NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED).Cast<INetwork>();
            foreach (var network in connectedNetworks)
            {
                if (network.IsConnected)
                {
                  network.GetTimeCreatedAndConnected(out uint _, out uint _, out uint 
                  pdwLowDateTimeConnected, out uint pdwHighDateTimeConnected);

                  DateTime networkConnectedTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long) 
                (((ulong)pdwHighDateTimeConnected << 32) | pdwLowDateTimeConnected));

                TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(networkConnectedTime);

                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + network.GetName() + "  Duration : {0} day(s) {1}:{2}:{3}", diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);
                     }
         }
```

Comment: you need to reference the netprofm.dll in the \windows\system32\ directory. Then add: 'using NETWORKLIST;'

Comment: Please refer this link for more details. https://codesanitize.com/unlock-c-network-secrets-uncover-adapter-status-isolate-virtual-networks/